# How to return variable that is exclusive to one subclass?

Tags: java, subclass

I have class `Person` which has multiple subclasses. All subclasses have the same variables (`name`, `address`, `phone`), but one has an extra variable, `rank`. I know how to display `name`, `address`, `phone` but I don't know how to display `rank`.

Define class:

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String phone;

    public Person(String name, String address, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getName() + "\n" + name;
    }
}
```

Define the subclass with `rank`:

```
public class Pupil extends Person {
    public String rank;
    public Student(String name, String address, String phone, String rank) {
        super(name, social, phone);
    }

}
```

Create `pupil` and display `name`, `address`, and `phone`.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Person person = new Person("John", "1 John Deer Rd", "1112223333");
Person pupil = new Pupil("Jane", "2 John Deer Rd", "1112223333", "junior");


System.out.println(pupil.name + "'s phone is " + pupil.phone + " and their address is " + pupil.address + "." + "\n");

}
}
```

How do I also display `rank`?

Comment: you can use toString()

Comment: If you don't want to do this via `toString()` you will have to do `instanceOf`/`(Pupil)` (or just give the variable `pupil` its proper type (`Pupil pupil = ..`)

Comment: BTW you forgot to store rank passed to constructor. So after `super(name, social, phone);` you should add `this.rank = rank;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the object from `Person` back to `Pupil`:

`((Pupil)pupil).rank`

And if you are not 100% sure that your object is actually a Pupil you should add a sanity-check:

```
if(pupil instanceof Pupil) {
    System.out.println(…+((Pupil)pupil).rank+…);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pupil 's constructor instead of Person's constructor

```
public class Pupil extends Person {
    public String rank;
    public Pupil (String name, String address, String phone, String rank) {
        super(name, social, phone);
    }

}
Pupil pupil = new Pupil("Jane", "2 John Deer Rd", "1112223333", "junior");pupil = new Pupil("Jane", "2 John Deer Rd", "1112223333", "junior");
System.out.println(pupil.name + "'s phone is " + pupil.phone + " and their address is " + pupil.address + "." + "\n"+pupil .rank);
```

I suggest using getter and setter methods and use them and make your fields private.
You can read [more about setter and getter methods](https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices)
a quick example:

```
public class Person {
private String name;
public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
this.name =name;
//get name parameter and set it to this class'sname parameter }
```

Last but not least, I recommend that you read about [this keyword](https://www.javatpoint.com/this-keyword)
be happy.